# EListError - how to prevent it

Tags: delphi

I open the ACRTable on on create event of the form.

This is what I have on after scroll of the table :

```
procedure TForm1.ACRTable1AfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if ACRTable1.FieldByName('COMPANY_ID').AsString <> '' then
begin
ACRQuery1.SQL.Text:= 'select * from MEMBERS where COMPANY_ID = ' +
ACRTable1.FieldByName('COMPANY_ID').AsString;
ACRQuery1.Open;
end;
end;
```

However if ACRQuery1 does not have any records I get database EListError.
I tried :

```
procedure TForm1.ACRQuery1BeforeOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if ACRQuery1.RecordCount =0  then
  label1.Caption:='No records found'
  else   label1.Caption:='';
end;
```

But still the same error.
What am I doing wrong ? How can I prevent this EListError ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which TDataSet-descendant type your ACRQuery1 is, but at a guess, it calculates its RecordCount from a TList or similar (e.g. by reading its Count property) which does not actually exist unless the dataset is open.  So, first thing I'd try would be to avoid attempting to read its RecordCount unless it is open:

```
procedure TForm1.ACRQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
//  Following is how I would have structured it
//  Make sure you remove your BeforeOpen handler
  if ACRQuery1.Active then begin
    if (ACRQuery1.RecordCount = 0) then
      label1.Caption := 'No records'
    else
      label1.Caption := IntToStr(ACRQuery1.RecordCount);
  end
  else begin
   label1.Caption:='No records found';
end;
```

Once the code is moved to the AfterOpen event, the check on the dataset being Acttive isn't really necessary as the event won't be called otherwise - moving the check on RecordCount into the AfterOpen event should avoid it being read while the dataset implementation can't return a value for it, but I've included a test for it in the code, just in case you try to use the code elsewhere.

Btw, if you still get the EListError using the above code, I'd say the cause is a bug in the implementation of TACRQuery, not anything you are doing "wrong", and you should report it to the author(s).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in what I first posted.  The other thing is that your code should be in the AfterOpen event.

Comment: No,unfortunately it still does not work. It seems that the afterscroll event of the table expects the query to produce a list. If no list is found I get the error. Soon as the query is opened I am screwed.

Comment: Well, if you have the source of your TACRQuery, you can try debugging it yourself:  Make sure you have "Use Debug DCUs" checked in your project's Debug options, let the exception happen and use the stack trace to see where it is triggered.